# How to save transparency on .eps file (Adobe Illustrator CC)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, eps

So I've drawn a design in Illustrator CC that has some transparency throughout the actual shapes (not just the background). When I save the file as a .eps and open in photoshop, the background remains transparent, but the shapes themselves are completely opaque again. How can I maintain the transparency when saving as a .eps from illustrator?

Comment: Why EPS? If you are using Photoshop, just save as a .ai file. EPS is a flat file format, .ai is not.

Comment: Why eps? Because some printers require it and frankly, an .ai file is not a final file to send for printing. They do accept .ai simply because lot of designers don't know how to "flatten" their nice effects and transparency.

Answer (score 1):

That would be because EPS is not a authoring format but rasterization instructions. It has no features to support transparency, layers etc that could be read back from the system.

(this is not because eps could not and does not have the ability to have transparency its just a interpretation issue)

Just open the AI file in Photoshop.

Comment: JooJaa's totally right on this one - saving as a .eps is an entirely unnecessary step when you can directly open the .ai in Photoshop. Depending on your project, you may also want to look into placing the artwork as Smart Objects, so you can update them in Illustrator if need be.

Answer (score 0):

Save the file in EPS10 format - it supports the transparency.